# How to specify a list of JVM parameters for Dockerized SpringBoot REST jar execution

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, microservices, jvm-arguments

I have a simple REST application developed using SpringBoot and this application jar has been deployed in a docker container. The end goal is to test the latency of this application under different JVM flag value combinations. I need to know how I can specify a long list of JVM flag values that can be repeatedly changed?

I know that you can specify one or two flags like this:
Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:9
ADD target/java-container.jar /usr/src/myapp/
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
EXPOSE 8080
CMD java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar java-container.jar
```

and running the command:

```
$ docker run -d --name mycontainer8g -p 8080:8080 -m 800M -e JAVA_OPTIONS='-Xmx300m' rafabene/java-container:openjdk-env
```

using the **JAVA_OPTIONS**. But I have a very long list of JVM flags as shown below:

```
-XX:+UseSerialGC -XX:+ResizePLAB -XX:-ResizeOldPLAB -XX:-AlwaysPreTouch -XX:-ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+ParallelRefProcBalancingEnabled -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:-ResizeTLAB -XX:-ZeroTLAB -XX:-FastTLABRefill -XX:+NeverActAsServerClassMachine -XX:-AlwaysActAsServerClassMachine -XX:+UseAutoGCSelectPolicy -XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+UsePSAdaptiveSurvivorSizePolicy -XX:-UseAdaptiveGenerationSizePolicyAtMinorCollection -XX:+UseAdaptiveGenerationSizePolicyAtMajorCollection -XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicyWithSystemGC -XX:+UseAdaptiveGCBoundary -XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicyFootprintGoal -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizeDecayMajorGCCost -XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:-CollectGen0First -XX:+BindGCTaskThreadsToCPUs -XX:+UseGCTaskAffinity -XX:YoungPLABSize=3397 -XX:OldPLABSize=1123 -XX:GCTaskTimeStampEntries=240 -XX:TargetPLABWastePct=6 -XX:PLABWeight=75 -XX:OldPLABWeight=46 -XX:MarkStackSize=4617021 -XX:MarkStackSizeMax=713160576 -XX:RefDiscoveryPolicy=0 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=48 -XX:MaxRAM=139765086242 -XX:ErgoHeapSizeLimit=0 -XX:MaxRAMFraction=4 -XX:DefaultMaxRAMFraction=4 -XX:MinRAMFraction=2 -XX:InitialRAMFraction=61 -XX:AutoGCSelectPauseMillis=5557 -XX:AdaptiveSizeThroughPutPolicy=0 -XX:AdaptiveSizePausePolicy=0 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyInitializingSteps=28 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyOutputInterval=0 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=12 -XX:AdaptiveTimeWeight=19 -XX:PausePadding=0 -XX:PromotedPadding=3 -XX:SurvivorPadding=3 -XX:ThresholdTolerance=10 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyCollectionCostMargin=49 -XX:YoungGenerationSizeIncrement=16 -XX:YoungGenerationSizeSupplement=104 -XX:YoungGenerationSizeSupplementDecay=9 -XX:TenuredGenerationSizeIncrement=22 -XX:TenuredGenerationSizeSupplement=117 -XX:TenuredGenerationSizeSupplementDecay=2 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=13557897735059052544 -XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=0 -XX:MaxGCMinorPauseMillis=16119267456708329472 -XX:GCTimeRatio=73 -XX:AdaptiveSizeDecrementScaleFactor=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizeMajorGCDecayTimeScale=11 -XX:MinSurvivorRatio=1 -XX:InitialSurvivorRatio=6 -XX:BaseFootPrintEstimate=272901592 -XX:GCHeapFreeLimit=2 -XX:PrefetchCopyIntervalInBytes=654 -XX:PrefetchScanIntervalInBytes=748 -XX:PrefetchFieldsAhead=1 -XX:ProcessDistributionStride=3
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Hi, you want something like: write the java_options in a file and use it as a parameter of the docker command?

Comment: try this, store command in file as run.sh and mount this file from local directory. update file locally and restarting contains might will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As A. Wolf said, I'd put all jvm options in a file and run

```
docker run --rm -d --name mycontainer8g -p 8080:8080 -m 800M -e JAVA_OPTIONS="$(cat myjavaoptions)" rafabene/java-container:openjdk-env
```

Answer (score 1):

While passing values using `.sh` is valid, you have so many params so I think that the clearer way is using `docker-compose`.

Just install it from [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) then you can specify in your `docker-compose.yml` something like this:

```
environment:
  - JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx128m -Xms128m
```

You will be able to change your configuration and then restart the container just typing:

- `docker-compose down`
- `docker-compose up -d`

Answer (score 0):

You can use --env-file parameter for passing multiple env variables.

docker run --env-file ./env.list image-name

Here env.list file will be list of env values you want to set inside docker container.